# How to get same propfind response for each request while listing icloud calendars?

Tags: calendar, icloud, webdav, caldav, propfind

I am listing calendars from icloud using caldav request propfind, I am able to get the calendar collection, but the output differs for each run. 
  The *calendar-enabled* and *current-user-principal* properties are missing some time and some time it shows, because of theat my code is failing.
  I need *calendar-enabled* property to check whether the calendar is enabled on mobile or not. 
  I did not changed anything at calendar level and at code between the runs.  Any solution please.

**This is the request method**

methodPropfind = (headers, auth, body, url, cb) ->
  options =
    method: 'PROPFIND'
    headers: headers
    auth: auth
    body: body
    url: url
  http options, cb
  return true

**body:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<propfind xmlns="DAV:" xmlns:D="http://apple.com/ns/ical/">
  <prop>
    <displayname/>
    <C:getctag xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <owner/>
    <D:calendar-color/>
    <D:calendar-order/>
    <current-user-privilege-set/>
    <invite xmlns:A="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"/>
    <D:calendar-enabled />
    <C:schedule-default-calendar-URL xmlns:C='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'/>
  </prop>
</propfind>
```

**Header:**

```
Depth:1
```

**Url**
 url is principal url.

I have converted xml response to javascript object, and this is one of the calendar from list which I am getting.

I am expecting "ExpectedOutput" for every run, but some time I am getting "NotExpectedOutput". Why it is differing?

*NotExpectedOutput:*

```
{ displayname: { _attributes: { xmlns: 'DAV:' }, _text: 'Family' },
  getctag:
   { _attributes: { xmlns: 'http://calendarserver.org/ns/' },
     _text: 'FT=-@RU=39505321-e02c-46a5-a9ba-544e5c3f0fac@S=678' },
  owner:
   { _attributes: { xmlns: 'DAV:' },
     href: { _text: '/1146333145/principal/' } },
  'calendar-color':
   { _attributes: { xmlns: 'http://apple.com/ns/ical/' },
     _text: '#FFCC00' },
  'calendar-order':
   { _attributes: { xmlns: 'http://apple.com/ns/ical/' },
     _text: '1001' },
  'current-user-privilege-set':
   { _attributes: { xmlns: 'DAV:' },
     privilege:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] } }
```

*ExpectedOutput*

```
 { displayname: { _text: 'Family' },
  getctag:
   { _attributes: { xmlns: 'http://calendarserver.org/ns/' },
     _text: 'FT=-@RU=39505321-e02c-46a5-a9ba-544e5c3f0fac@S=678' },
  owner: { href: { _text: '/11463333145/principal/' } },
  'calendar-color':
   { _attributes:
      { xmlns: 'http://apple.com/ns/ical/',
        'symbolic-color': 'yellow' },
     _text: '#FFCC00' },
  'calendar-order':
   { _attributes: { xmlns: 'http://apple.com/ns/ical/' },
     _text: '1001' },
  'current-user-privilege-set':
   { privilege:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
  'current-user-principal': { href: { _text: '/11463335145/principal/' } },
  'calendar-enabled':
   { _attributes: { xmlns: 'http://apple.com/ns/ical/' },
     _text: 'true' } }
```